# Why can't I install c# mono plugin on Eclipse?

Tags: c#, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to install http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/downloadinfos.html#Download+via+update+site on eclipse sdk 3.2.2

but I get this message. I'd like not to upgrade eclipse due to other plugin. Is it possible to fix this ?

It is supposed to work
http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/requirements.html

o use this plug-in you will need:

Eclipse 3.2 or newer (Tested on Eclipse 3.2.2, 3.3, and 3.4 development line)

Comment: What's the error message you got when installing mono plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark since you haven't told us what the problem is... did you try another update site?  There are three sites listed on http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/downloadinfos.html.